# MVC4, WebSocket, Safari context.IsWebSocketRequest is false

Tags: safari, websocket, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Windows 8 with IIS8 and MVC4 to establish a websocketconnection. This works fine with Firefox, IE10 and Chrome. Safari still wont let me establish a websocketconnection. My Handlercode looks like this:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
{
Client client = new Client();
context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(client.HoldConnection);
}
}
```

The Problem is that context.IsWebSocketRequest is always false, while conntecting via Safari. My JavaScript code is a simple `this.socket = new WebSocket(window.WebSocketUrl);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two incompatible versions of the websocket protocol in use.  Safari uses the original (now deprecated) [Hixie](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-hixie-thewebsocketprotocol-76) variant; Firefox, IE10 and Chrome use the newer [Hybi](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) variant

Its quite possible to build a websocket server that speaks both versions but it sounds like MVC4 only supports Hybi clients.

Safari will eventually catch up.  If you can't wait for this you could consider either using an alternative server which supports both websocket variants or rework your clients to poll instead (either as standard or as a fall-back when websocket connection fails).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I think I can wait. Do you know whether the ios version of safari also "speaks" Hixie?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid iOS Safari also speaks Hixie

Comment: You can also try using SignalR. We have implemented listening to message bus successfully using SignalR. And it works fine for all clients.

Comment: Yea, I allready read about SignalR, but I think we will stick with websockets, cause it will be (or maybe allready is) a standard, so why dont use it. We dont need to support older browsers.

Comment: FYI: Its working with the nightly build of webkit, so it will be in iOS6.