# Websocket on Microsoft Azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis, websocket

I have a question : Does the websockets can run on a website host on Microsoft Azure ?

I use to host a website on a Windows server 2012 with IIS8, in order to use the websocket (the .Net 4.5 native ones, including the websockethandler.ashx, etc). I just upload my website on a Microsoft Azure server, and obviously, there is not IIS8, and it's not working anymore.

```
if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
```

is now returning false.

*How can I run the websockets on a Azure server, on the Cloud ??*

Comment: Can you provide a bit more info about your deployment? Is this Cloud Services or VM with Windows Server? The answer varies depending on that :)

Comment: Sorry, I just update my post, it's on the cloud

Comment: Windows Azure provides, in the cloud, three services you could use to host a website: [Cloud Services](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/cloud-services/), [Virtual Machines](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/) and [Web Sites](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/web-sites/). Each has varying degrees of automation and control. Which of these are you using?

Comment: Cloud Services, as Web role

Answer (score 2):

If you are running in Cloud Services, you will need to be running under osFamily 3. This is how you get your base instance to be running Windows Server 2012. You can find this in your .cscfg file [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff729420.aspx) another [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg456324.aspx)

The default project setting was osFamily 1 (Windows Server 2008) which did not support WebSockets. osFamily 2 was Windows Server 2008 R2 which also did not support WebSockets.

Comment: I'll look at that asap, and let you know :)

Comment: It's done. I'm running under osFamily 3 in Cloud Services, still not working.

Comment: Now that the server supports WebSockets... What is the client side of your app running in? Are you running into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10723473/mvc4-websocket-safari-context-iswebsocketrequest-is-false

Comment: I'm running my client side using a web page, on google chrome. ("Chrome is up to date").

Answer (score 0):

According to [this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/11/04/windows-azure-import-export-hard-drives-vm-acls-web-sockets-remote-debugging-continuous-delivery-new-relic-billing-alerts-and-more.aspx#Web%20Sites%3a%20Web%20Sockets%20Support), now you can use Web Sockets with Windows Azure Web Sites.